# Java constructor not initializing properly

Tags: java, class

I have a class that has this 2 constructors:

```
public Conferencia(String nomeConferencia, 
                   String localizacaoConferencia, 
                   int anoConferencia, 
                   int mesConferencia, 
                   int diaConferencia) 
{
    this.nomeConferencia = nomeConferencia;
    this.localizacaoConferencia = localizacaoConferencia;
    this.anoConferencia = anoConferencia;
    this.mesConferencia = mesConferencia;
    this.diaConferencia = diaConferencia;
    this.membroComiteOrganizacao = new MembroComiteOrganizacao[100];
    this.membroComitePrograma = new MembroComitePrograma[100];
    this.idConferencia = contadorConferencias++;
}


public Conferencia(String nomeConferencia, 
                   String localizacaoConferencia, 
                   int anoConferencia, 
                   int mesConferencia, 
                   int diaConferencia, 
                   MembroComiteOrganizacao[] membroComiteOrganizacao) 
{
    this.nomeConferencia = nomeConferencia;
    this.localizacaoConferencia = localizacaoConferencia;
    this.anoConferencia = anoConferencia;
    this.mesConferencia = mesConferencia;
    this.diaConferencia = diaConferencia;
    this.membroComiteOrganizacao = membroComiteOrganizacao;
    this.idConferencia = contadorConferencias++;
}
```

`MembroComiteOrganizacao` constructor is like this:

```
public MembroComiteOrganizacao(int papelMembro, 
                               String memberName, 
                               String memberEmail, 
                               String memberInstituicao) 
{
    super(memberName, memberEmail, memberInstituicao);
    this.papelMembro = papelMembro;

}
```

In `main`, to not have to insert always data if i create something like this:

```
static Conferencia[] conferencias = {new Conferencia("Congresso 1","Abrantes",2012,1,2)};
```

All is ok.

But now I want to insert in that same constructor data regarding `MembroComiteOrganização`. I've done:

```
static Conferencia[] conferencias = {new Conferencia("Congresso 1","Abrantes",2012,1,2,new MembroComiteOrganizacao(1,"Regina Kareem Obrien","imc2oep-m.4oa@0o2z09s.com","Casa da Criança de Tires"))};
```

but it gives me error.

Can someone explain-me what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE

done

```
static Conferencia[] conferencias = {new Conferencia("Congresso 1","Abrantes",2012,1,2,new MembroComiteOrganizacao[1](1,"Regina Kareem Obrien","imc2oep-m.4oa@0o2z09s.com","Casa da Criança de Tires"))};
```

and the error now is 
    `')' expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is really the only constructor you have in your Conferencia class, then even your first code snipped would fail, since the MembroComiteOrganizacao parameter is not optional and you are not passing value to it.

The other one fails because that parameter is an array, and you are passing a single object.

If you define the last parameter as `MembroComiteOrganizacao... membroComiteOrganizacao` instead of `MembroComiteOrganizacao[] membroComiteOrganizacao` (i.e. you use `...` instead of `[]`), both your code snippets should work.

Comment: done static Conferencia[] conferencias = {new Conferencia("Congresso 1","Abrantes",2012,1,2,new MembroComiteOrganizacao[1](1,"Regina Kareem Obrien","imc2oep-m.4oa@0o2z09s.com","Casa da Criança de Tires"))}; and now the error is ')' expected

Comment: If you don't want to change your constructor to use `...` instead of `[]`, then you have to pass the following as the last parameter: `new MembroComiteOrganizacao[]{new MembroComiteOrganizacao(1,"Regina Kareem Obrien","imc2oep-m.4oa@0o2z09s.com","Casa da Criança de Tires")}`

Comment: Btw, if you do replace `[]` with `...` in your constructor, then you can remove the first one (that does not take the last parameter) as the `...` tells Java the parameter is optional - so Java treats it as an array which can have 0 to many elements (depending on how many MembroComiteOrganizacao instances you pass to it). So that may be the thing you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

while creating `static Conferencia[] conferencias` at index 0, the c'tor is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your types don't match up, your Conferencia constructor takes an array of MembroComiteOrganizacao, but you give it one instance, not an array.